# Access Denied Signed URL Python3 using cloud front

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, cryptography, amazon-cloudfront, signed-url

I am trying to create signed urls for my s3 bucket to which only select people will have access to until the time expires.

I am not able to find the issue in my code. Please help

```
import boto
from boto.cloudfront import CloudFrontConnection
from boto.cloudfront.distribution import Distribution
import base64
import json 
import rsa
import time                                                                                                                                                              

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    url = "https://notYourUrl.com/example.html"                                                                                                                                                                      
    expires = int(time.time() + 36000)
    
    pem = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
               myKey
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

Cloudfront console
    key_pair_id = 'myKey'    
    
    policy = {
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Resource":url,
                "Condition":{
                    "DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":expires},
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    
    policy = json.dumps(policy)
    private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(pem)
    
    policy = policy.encode("utf-8")
    signed = rsa.sign(policy, private_key, 'SHA-1')
    policy = base64.b64encode(policy)
    policy = policy.decode("utf-8")
    signature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signed)
    signature = signature.decode("utf-8")
    
    policy = policy.replace("+", "-")
    policy = policy.replace("=", "_")
    policy = policy.replace("/", "~")
    
    signature = signature.replace("+", "-")
    signature = signature.replace("=", "_")
    signature = signature.replace("/", "~")

    print("%s?Expires=%s&Signature=%s&Key-Pair-Id=%s" % (url,expires, signature, key_pair_id))
```

When I test the file on lambda I am able to produce and print a URL but when I access the URL I receive an access denied error message from the XML file.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong at this point. To test if I am able to generated any SignedUrl I created a node.js lambda in which I am successfully able to generate the URL and even access my page.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many failed tries to make my code work I decided to go with a different approach and used node.js to fullfill my needs. The code below works perfectly and I am able to generate signed url's

For now I used a hardcoded time value to test my code and will later on work on getting that dynamically using datetime.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var keyPairId = 'myKeyPairId';
var privateKey = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' + '\n' +

    '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';
var signer = new AWS.CloudFront.Signer(keyPairId, privateKey);

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var options = {url: "https://notYourUrl.com/example.html", expires: 1621987200, 'Content-Type': 'text/html'};
    //console.log(options);
    const cookies = signer.getSignedCookie(options);
    const url = signer.getSignedUrl(options);
    
    console.log("Printing URL "+url);
    console.log(cookies);
  
};
```